# unexpected EOF while parsing in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error everytime i run this code using .format()

**Code:**

```
list_A = [1,2,3,4] #Declaring List_A with items 1,2,3,4
list_B = [6,7,8,9] #Declaring List_B with items 5,6,7,8
print("list_A is: {} and list_B is: {}".format(list_A, list_B)) #Prints list_A and list_B
print("length of list_A is: {0} and length of list_B is: {1}".format(len(list_A), len(list_B)) #Prints length of list_A with list_B
```

**Output**

```
File "<ipython-input-76-d54f829c5c52>", line 5
print("length of list_A is: {0} and length of list_B is: {1}".format(len(list_A), len(list_B)) #Prints length of list_A with len()
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: You’re missing a `)`.

Comment: For future reference, if your editor can’t help you find and avoid these problems, consider using a more powerful editor or IDE or installing a Python plugin for whichever one you’re using. Once you learn that these errors usually come from a missing `)`, `]`, or `}` on a precious line it’s pretty to debug them, but it’s even easier when your editor is screaming at you before you even try to run the code.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was stuck for past 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parathesis.

```
print("length of list_A is: {0} and length of list_B is: {1}".format(len(list_A), len(list_B))) #Prints length of list_A with list_B
```